# How do I know when a form represents an integral cohomology class?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, homology-cohomology

Suppose $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold, and $\omega \in \Omega^p(M)$ is a closed $p$-form. Moreover, assume that $d\omega = 0$, so that it represents a de Rham cohomology class.

I would like to understand the meaning of the following sentence that I read in a book about geometric quantisation: **$\omega$ represents an integral cohomology class**.

Here's what I thought: we have the Poincaré isomorphism $\Phi : H_{dR}^p(M) \rightarrow {H_p}(M, \mathbb{R})^*$, where:

$$H_{dR}^p(M) = \text{$p$th de Rham cohomology group;}$$
$${H_p}(M, \mathbb{R}) = \text{$p$th differentiable singular homology group;}$$

and the star denotes the dual. This isomorphism is given by integration of the given form over the corresponding $p$-cycle.

Now, since we have a natural inclusion ${H_p}(M, \mathbb{Z}) \subseteq {H_p}(M, \mathbb{R})$, I could say that $\omega \in \Omega^p(M)$ represents an integral cohomology class when $\Phi(\omega) \in {H_p}(M, \mathbb{Z})$. But this is basically saying that the integral of $\omega$ over any differentiable $p$-cycle is an integer. Surely this cannot hold, except for trivial cases. So what does it mean to represent an integral cohomology class?

I would also like to know: **when does the volume form of a closed manifold represents an integral cohomology class, and why?**

Thank you.

Comment: That's exactly what it means, and it holds in lots of nontrivial cases.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks for your comment, but how can I see that? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Everything you said is correct until "surely this cannot hold..."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What I want is to understand that this holds in nontrivial cases, so I guess this amounts to finding some explicit examples.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Dear Qiaochu, The second sentence of your last comment is not true.  (When $n > 1$, it is not true for a general vector in $\mathbb R^n$ that some multiple of it lies in $\mathbb Z^n$.)  Nevertheless, the general spirit of this comment is correct, of course.  Regards,

Comment: No, no, there is a misstatement that is leading the OP to say "surely this cannot hold." The sentence before that is wrong: Only over differentiable $p$-cycles that represent *integral* homology classes, not all!

Comment: @Matt: My apologies! I was thinking of the $1$-dimensional case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With regard to your last question, you're on a good path for examples. Following @Qiaochu's first example, we have the closed $2$-form $\omega$ that generates $H^2(\mathbb R^3-\{0\}) \cong H^2(S^2)$:

$$\omega = \frac{x\,dy\wedge dz + y\, dz\wedge dx + z\, dx\wedge dy}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,.$$

This should look familiar if you interpret it as the flux $2$-form of the gravitational or electric force with a particle at the origin and think of Gauss's Law. As it stands, this $2$-form is not integral, as the integral over any closed surface containing the origin, say, the unit sphere, is $4\pi$. But we can normalize and get an integral class: $\frac1{4\pi}\omega$ is now the generator of $H^2(S^2,\mathbb Z)$.

You can make this work analogously by normalizing "the" volume form for any compact, orientable $n$-manifold.

However, one of @Qiaochu's statements is wrong. If we take $M=S^2(1)\times S^2(\pi)$ (where by these numbers I mean radii), then the element of $H^2(M)$ that corresponds to the sum of the respective area forms (officially, pulled back by the canonical projections) is not an integral class, and no scalar multiple of it is (because $H^2(M)\cong \mathbb R\oplus\mathbb R$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So for a top degree form $\omega$ to be integral, it's enough to check that its integral over $M$ is an integer, since $H^n(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is generated by a single element ($M$ being connected, of course).

Answer (score 15):

On $M = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0, 0) \}$ consider the differential form

$$\omega = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{x \, dy - y \, dx}{x^2 + y^2}.$$

This is a closed $1$-form. Its integral over a path in $M$ is its [winding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number); in particular, it is always an integer.

For nontrivial examples of integral $2$-forms you just need to find examples of nontrivial complex [line bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_bundle). More precisely, any such form is the [curvature form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_form) of a [connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_form) on a complex line bundle $L$, and the corresponding integral cohomology class is the [first Chern class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class) $c_1(L)$ of $L$. This is a special case of [Chern-Weil theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern-Weil_theory). This example comes up in physics when discussing Dirac's quantization argument; see, for example, [this paper by Bott](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=4rmJUkWOitgC&oi=fnd&pg=PA129&dq=bott+on+some+recent+interactions&ots=_ywrJlikhP&sig=I-0uGFb1QpRc7L9Nv6Vs4hGhR5E#v=onepage&q=bott%20on%20some%20recent%20interactions&f=false).

Comment: Oh, I forgot about this classical example. Thanks for reminding me and for pointing out Bott's paper, which is very informative.